# Where does Windows store the "last used path" information?

Tags: windows-7

For example, an application has a button, clicking on the button opens the "open file" dialog.
The first time you use the button, the dialog takes you to the default path. most likely "My Documents".
But subsequent clicks take you to the path you visited last time, even if the application itself doesn't handle this at all(I've tried it with a 1 line .NET WinForm Application). So the OS must be maintaining the "last used path" kind of info for the applications.
So I'm wondering where Windows store this info?
If I want to erase this info, how should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try following windows registry (regedit). Not tested.

XP

> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Comdlg32\LastVisitedMRU

Vista, Win7, Win8, Win10

> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Comdlg32\LastVisitedPidlMRU

Source: http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/LastVisitedMRU

Comment: include your source. Add if you tested either of those. And don't say "vista and above", because in the future a version of windows might come that stores it in a different place.

Comment: I updated my post by your request

Comment: Don't say <=XP.  How far back are you going before XP.  Win 3.1?  Win 95 ?

Comment: Thank you. I exported that key, run my application to open a file in a different folder, export that key again. Then compared the 2 exports, bingo!

Comment: Nice David, you are welcome.